# Possible to abort MVC action and keep view the same (without re-writing the view's GET "load code")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC5 web app.

I have a view based on a complex viewmodel. In the main GET method I'm filling this viewmodel, setting certain ViewBag items, etc.... I'll refer to this as the "load code" for now.

So, my view is basically a data entry form. Business rules are fairly complex. When the user hits the save button I do a POST and run some c# code which checks rules, etc... If it FAILS, I simply want to "abort" the action and show the user the same GET view.

My question involves all that was done to initially load the view: The ViewBag code, filling of viewmodel, etc.... Do I have to write this "load code" again in my POST? This seems very redundant. Is there a way I can just "abort" the ActionResult/POST and show the GET view?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

**** update/clarification - based on comments ****

I suppose this question is more of a "general" one. Can you "abort" the POST and go "back" to the GET View without re-running all the "load code" (for the dropdowns, populating the viewmodel, etc....)

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: There are plenty ways to solve this. But without Code Example of your Controller Methods (I guess you have a Controller) its very difficult to give a right answer.

Comment: First, use client side validation and ajax when possible to avoid the full trip back. Second, factor out your view model load into a proc like "LoadCustomerViewModel".

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this question is more of a "general" one then. Can you "abort" the POST and go "back" to the GET View without re-running all the "load code" (for the dropdowns, populating the viewmodel, etc....)

Comment: No. MVC is stateless so you need to reload everything on your view. Minimize this with client side validation, ajax calls and breaking large views into partial views. I've never seen this be an issue given all the things MVC can do for you (model binding, caching, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to server and validate and then decide if you want to accept the POST or Fails/Abort and keep the previous page with all the values 
then I'll suggest you to handle this in AJAX.
Create a third action/API Method and keep your validation logic there. then on the form submit hit the validation action using ajax and server will return True/False (with any error message) if you get True from server then let the javascript post your form otherwise show any error message and return false to stop posting the form and stay on the page.
For example use a javascript method to validate.

```
<form onsubmit="return isValidForm()" />
```

function

```
function isValidForm(){
    //// hit the server and see if you want to proceed with the POST
    //// if fails return false so your form will not be posted and all of your values will remains the same, here before return false you can clear the form if needed.
}
```

let me know if you need more information.